# How to create Master/Detail view with two datagrids in ColdFusion

Tags: datagrid, coldfusion, cfgrid

In Coldfusion, I have Master and Detail data that I need to display in two separate cfgrids;  like the typical Customers/Orders scenario.  My cfgrids are bound to cfc functions which populate the cfgrids.  In my current dataset, only one Customer has Orders and when I click on this record in the Master datagrid the Detail datagrid displays the related records.  But when I click on a record in the Master datagrid that has no related detail records, the Detail datagrid does not refresh but maintains display of the previous data.  Also the search icon within the datagrid's control panel indicates it is searching for values rather than displaying the Refresh icon.

Can you please show me how to establish Master and Detail cfgrids where I can see Orders of Customers as I navigate through the Master datagrid?

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated!

Maklar

Answer (score 1):

bind one of the master grid's columns (e.g. customerID) as one of the parameters of the details grid.

Answer (score 0):

Please check 'appendKey' and 'selectMode' attributes are set correctly